# Mapping function: Nested object inside array not consecutively printed

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mapping

Given a function below, i want to map _s from res to another function via return value from manipulateValidateReqRes function

```
CODE WAS UPDATED BELOW
```

why i cant return _s from map res.map function? it says TypeError: Object has no member 'map'

**UPDATED**

For clearly explanation and update debug process, i give my latest code below

```
const res = {
            "valid_data": [
                {
                    "shipper_name": "automate sender1",
                    "rts_reasons": [
                        "a reason"
                    ],
                    "rts_score": 0
                },
                {
                    "shipper_name": "automate sender2",
                    "rts_reasons": [
                        "a reason"
                    ],
                    "rts_score": 0
                }
            ],
            "shipping_rates": [
                {
                    "reguler": {
                        "summary_price": "7.000",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "_s": "9917xxx",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "reguler": {
                        "summary_price": "7.000",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "_s": "9918xxx",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "errors": [
                [],
                []
            ]
        }
        
      const manipulateRequest = Object.values(res).map((obj) => {
  return {
      // what key do you want?
                shipper_name: res.valid_data[0].shipper_name
                //_s: i want return _s value to manipulateRequest from res variable
  }
  })
  
  const postBulkPayload = {
    "filename": "filename1.xlsx",
    "total_order": manipulateRequest.length,
    "is_use_new_payment": true,
    "template_name": "bulk-order-with-postal_code-and-sub_district_name",
    "details": manipulateRequest,
    "cancelToken": {
        "promise": {}
    }
}
  console.log(postBulkPayload)
```

and for the result is

```
{
  filename: 'filename1.xlsx',
  total_order: 3,
  is_use_new_payment: true,
  template_name: 'bulk-order-with-postal_code-and-sub_district_name',
  details: [
    { shipper_name: 'automate sender1' },
    { shipper_name: 'automate sender1' },
    { shipper_name: 'automate sender1' }
  ],
  cancelToken: { promise: {} }
}
```

why does automate sender2 is not printed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue causing your particular error is that the JSON is returned as an object, and objects do not have a `.map` method. One option is to use the `Object.values` method like so:

```
const manipulateRequest = Object.values(res).map((obj, index) => {
     return {
                    _s: res.data.shipping_rates[index].reguler.data[index]._s
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this code returning an object with the _s property. You're likely trying to simply return the value of the _s property and store it as a value in the `manipulateRequest` array:

```
const manipulateRequest = Object.values(res).map((obj, index) => {
     return obj.shipping_rates[index].reguler.data[index]._s;
}
```

It would be wise to do some validation on this to ensure the properties exist and property data types are correct.

Also, you're using the index for the `res` object to reference the `shipping_rates` array and the `data` array, which isn't going to work.

For the sake of testing, you could just return the first item in the shipping_rates array:

```
const manipulateRequest = Object.values(res).map((obj, index) => {
     return {
                    _s: res.data.shipping_rates[0].reguler.data[0]._s
    }
}
```

Noticed I replaced the `index` variable with the static 0 index. This will work, but it won't account for any changes in data structure later on.

Comment: I appreciate for your response, sorry for ambiguous explanation. I mean i need correction as your mention on the first script - return as object. So I try your code with little correction: ```_s: res.shipping_rates[index].reguler.data[index]._s```  but the result is ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reguler')```

Comment: @Guinglain This is probably because your using the index variable for the current shipping_rates index. This index variable relates to the res iteration, not the shipping_rates array. I made an edit to the answer that may help you out.